Flask рандомизированный текст в качестве страницы
Так, у меня есть функция randomstring()
она отвечает за рандомизированный роут страницы
Её код:
def randomword():
        app.secret_key = ''.join(random.choice(
        string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase) for x in range(32))

и у меня есть роут {randomword}/login с методом post в котором есть форма логина
при нажатии кнопки войти меня должно перенести на {randomword}, но я не знаю как это реализовать в html
